# How can I use Chartist.js in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to draw chart where popup.html at chrome extension.

I followed "getting started" in official Chartist page.[https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html]

But it is not working.

My code is below:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            width : 250px; min-height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth">chart test</div>
   <div id="viewer"></div>
</body>
```

Chartist.js

```
var data = {
// A labels array that can contain any sort of values
labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
  series: [
    [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
 };

// Create a new line chart object where as first parameter we pass in a selector
// that is resolving to our chart container element. The Second parameter
// is the actual data object.
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);
```

I got a log "Chartist is not defined" where is "new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data)"

Comment: Does it make a difference if you move your `<script src="chartist.min.js">` tag to just before the `</body>` element?